# React Native Bubble Transition

Tags: view, react-native, transition

Is it possible to do this view transition in React Native:
https://appetize.io/app/tck0418dftyfjxkqrfu34rwt44?device=iphone5s&scale=75&orientation=portrait&osVersion=9.3

I just need a hint.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. Look into the `Animated` API and use it to tween the element size, position and border radius.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to change the styling of a view after animation ends ?

Comment: Yes - you can pass a callback function to `Animated.start` and change your styles there, perhaps by `setState` in the component which causes a re-render.